# Hello world in testng test throwing String index out of range error

Tags: testng, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to testNG, and I got a working environment from my friend. As part of that, I've just written a Hello World testNG class in java and a Test method. When I tried to run it threw:

> String index out of range: -2 error

Not sure how to debug the code as there is no such code accepting parameters

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HelloTest{

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How are you running your TestNG test in eclipse? Can you please post a screenshot of that also ?

Comment: I've just opened an issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/348

Comment: Do you see any relate stack trace on error log view? (Window -> show view -> error log). That will help locate where throw the index out of bound exception.